# How can I change UITableView height to its content height and still have clickable content?

Tags: ios, tableview

So I have a tableview where I changed the size to match its content size with this code.

```
CGRect testF = table1.frame;
testF.size.height = table1.contentSize.height;
table1.frame = testF;
```

But when I try to click any of the items I can only click the top two or the section in the red, because that is the initial height of the table in the beginning.

[image]

Is there a way around this, to dynamically change its height and still keep it clickable?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I change the height of a UITableView to fit its dynamic content?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194136/how-do-i-change-the-height-of-a-uitableview-to-fit-its-dynamic-content)

Comment: I used that to change the size but it wasn't clickable, either way Kris solved my problem.

Comment: Cool, glad you got it sorted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would think that the problem is not that you re sized the tableview, but that there is something that is blocking those touch events.  Perhaps you have some other view in the way or the tableview is nested inside of another view which has a frame set to the tappable area that you see but has clips to bounds off so you are able to see the tableview outside of it.  Try doing something like the following and see if it works, this should test my theory out:

```
table1.superview.frame = cgrectMake(table1.superview.frame.origin.x, table1.superview.frame.origin.y, testF.size.width, testF.size.height);
```

Add this under the code you showed above.

Comment: Oh wow, lol, glad I could help.  I was thinking like, theres a 10% chance this could actually be the issue.

Comment: Lol I think it's because I'm using a nested view like you said. Either way it worked so thanks again! Side note: Small world but I live in MI too.

Comment: Livonia. I worked for Title Source last year as an intern and saw that you're working for Quicken? (google stalking lol)

Comment: Lol yah, on the mobile team.